# How to mock getWcmMode() using mockito

Tags: aem, wcm

In AEM, there is a Java USE class wherein following code is present getWcmMode().isEdit()

Now, I am struggling to mock this object using mockito in Test java class. Is there any way we can do that?

Comment: what did you try? are you getting an error?

Comment: getting null pointer at getWcmMode().

Answer (score 2):

`getWcmMode()` is a final method in `WCMUsePojo`, mockito does not support mocking final methods by default.

you will have to enable it by creating a file named `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` in classpath (put it in the test resources/mockito-extensions folder) and put the following  single line

```
mock-maker-inline
```

then you can use `when` to specify function return values as usual-

```
  @Test
  public void testSomeComponetnInNOTEDITMode() {
    //setup wcmmode
    SightlyWCMMode fakeDisabledMode = mock(SightlyWCMMode.class);
    when(fakeDisabledMode.isEdit()).thenReturn(false);

    //ComponentUseClass extends WCMUsePojo
    ComponentUseClass fakeComponent = mock(ComponentUseClass.class);
    when(fakeComponent.getWcmMode()).thenReturn(fakeDisabledMode);

    assertFalse(fakeComponent.getWcmMode().isEdit());

    //do some more not Edit mode testing on fakeComponent.

  }
```